# SQL Server 2012, geography.STContains, wrong result?

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012, `geography.STContains` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929274.aspx)) and I don't get why the code below fails.

If I switch to `geometry` it works.

Can someone explain?

//Daniel

```
declare @geo geography
set @geo = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((17.519133203852 59.8297423369731, 17.5190071588812 59.8296936773323, 17.5189979955459 59.8298203729009, 17.5191345140461 59.8298223425544, 17.519133203852 59.8297423369731))', 4326)

-- Is not within
declare @p1 geography
set @p1 = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(17.5184709839477 59.829925754067)', 4326)

-- Is within
declare @p2 geography
set @p2 = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(17.519060 59.829774)', 4326) 

select
    @geo.STContains(@p1), -- should be 0 is 1
    @geo.STContains(@p2) -- should be 1 is 0
```

**UPDATED:**
If I invert them it works just fine, but then I don't get this:

```
declare @geo geography
set @geo = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((17.519133203852 59.8297423369731, 17.5190071588812 59.8296936773323, 17.5189979955459 59.8298203729009, 17.5191345140461 59.8298223425544, 17.519133203852 59.8297423369731))', 4326)

select
    @geo.STAsText() Polygon,
    @geo.STPointN(1).STAsText() Point1,
    @geo.STPointN(1).Lat Point1Latitud,
    @geo.STPointN(1).Long Point1Longitude
```

Which results in this:

```
Polygon 
POLYGON ((17.519133203852 59.8297423369731, 17.5190071588812 59.8296936773323, 17.5189979955459 59.8298203729009, 17.5191345140461 59.8298223425544, 17.519133203852 59.8297423369731))

Point1  
POINT (17.519133203852 59.8297423369731)

Point1Latitud   
59,8297423369731

Point1Longitude
17,519133203852
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found the issue. The user drew the polygon starting lower-right and went clockwise. If I reorder the points from biggest latitude and then go counterwise by sorting on long, lat it works. Found a helper for it, but that only works if you "know it's wrong":

```
if(sqlGeography.EnvelopeAngle() > 90)
    sqlGeography ? sqlGeography.ReorientObject();
```

Just put together a small solution that will fix my values: https://github.com/danielwertheim/GeographyFactory

and a blogpost about it: http://danielwertheim.se/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position/

and a follow up about the real "issue", the left-hand rule:

http://danielwertheim.se/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position-no/

Comment: I wouldn't think the start position would matter, but I'd agree that the clockwise/anti-clockwise aspect should.

Comment: The only listed rule in the documentation is the left-hand rule.

Comment: [Spatial Data Types Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx): "If we use the geography data type to store the spatial instance, we must specify the orientation of the ring and accurately describe the location of the instance. The interior of the polygon in an ellipsoidal system is defined by the left-hand rule.". This is a change from the 2008 rules (which said you had to occupy less than a hemisphere, which was a different rule to uniquely identify the inside and outside of a polygon on a continuous surface such as a sphere)

Comment: BTW. It really seems to work even if you start most "right hand" as long as you go counter-clockwise.

Comment: That's not really what the left-hand rule is about - try the quote from [this site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/499c6a42-caa4-420b-a1cf-17b869e0e242/): "if you were to walk along the ring between the points of the polygon, in the order in which they are listed, the interior of the polygon will be on your left-hand side. The exterior is on the right hand side. Therefore, if you are looking down on the polygon from above, the points of exterior rings should be defined in anti-clockwise order while interior rings should be listed in clockwise order."